# using yield in c# over a collection still I can't update my collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, ienumerable, yield-return

```
 static List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach(var number in GetNumbers())
        {
            if (number == 1)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(() => 
                {
                    numbers.Add(234567);
                });
                t.Start();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

    }



    public static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
    {

        for(int i =0; i <=10;i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i);
        }
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            yield return number;
        }            

    }
```

In the above example, I was iterating over collection using yield and added an item into the collection to get the updated number.

**I understand modifying a collection which we are iterating throws a collection modified exception but with IEnumerable, I get deferred execution and I should be able to add to the main collection as yield would return data one by one.**

I understand, removing an item could be problematic but adding an item to iterating collection should not be problem. However,if it is not allowed as what I have seen in above example(even it is deferred execution), what if I have situation like this:

"There is a large collection and so many consumers are iterating over it using IEnumerable and yield. They take each item, do some processing with this item.

and If there is any new item added into main list or collection, then client should get the latest item too.

Comment: You need to send and instance of the object to the thread.  So using start.BeginInvoke(stateobject) should work

Comment: Your code isn't thread-safe, so repairing the yield issue is futile.

Comment: You did provide a good mcve but infortunately this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to describe the constraints in your actual situation.

Comment: Instead of using a `List` you might want to consider using a `Queue` (`ConcurrentQueue`  in your case). You can test when there is a new item in the Queue when iterating over it by using `Pop` and consumers can `Push` changes on the queue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)

Answer (score 3):

Even though you are using yield, you are using it **inside** a foreach.

[The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety) state:

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but
>   issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read.

This is the fundamental issue here - you are reading the collection (as evidenced by the foreach) while writing to it. That just isn't allowed.

This may be worth reading - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a90c87be-9553-4d48-9892-d482ee325f02/why-cant-change-value-in-foreach?forum=csharpgeneral

*You likely want to consider using ConcurrentBag, ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentStack as alternatives.*

Comment: Does this help @YogeshJoshi ?